# jQuery html() cannot get <input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've came across with this weird behavior, not quite sure what I'm doing wrong
Tried searching but no luck...

So basically, I had a simple input, can be anything

```
<input class="me" type="text" name="me" value="3"></input>
```

Then I want to copy itself

```
$(".me").after($(".me").html());
```

But somehow it's not working, any suggestions? Please note that I don't need .val() and create a new one, I want to copy the whole input tag as there'll be input, textarea, select, etc... Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/GEWQ9/1/

P.S. if I choose span instead of input, it works fine, which is weird

Comment: Void elements don't have closing tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because `.html()` get innerHTML, and input element does not have any inner html, you need to [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the input element

```
$(".me").after($(".me").clone());
```

Comment: Argh! that's why! innerHtml is the key word, it works! thanks! I'll come back in 12 mins and accept the answer

Comment: you can't accept answer within 15min, at least i can't

Comment: @C-link ignore them every forum will have its own share of crazys

Answer (score 0):

Just call the clone tag

```
$(".me").after($(".me").clone());
```

Comment: don't copy paste answers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't refreshed my page and somebody gave you an answer already :D